# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_pixFindSkew"

Tags: objective-c, tesseract, leptonica

I installed [Tesseract-OCR-iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS) using Cocoapods and imported `<TesseractOCR/allheaders.h>` in the .m file. Tesseract is working, but I can't use any Leptonica functions declared in the `allheaders.h` file.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you link to the actual lib under the build phases tab?

Comment: Thanks, easy solution!